# Getting 2d array from python and inserting it in MongoDB using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I want to insert data inside a collection in mongoDB using Node.js. The data which I want to insert is coming from python in the form of 2d array like this

[[1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1]]

what I want is to insert this data in mongoDB like this

{number : 1,2,3,4} //first row
{number : 4,3,2,1} //second row

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

var myPythonScript = "demo.py";
var pythonExecutable = "/usr/local/bin/python3.7";

var uint8arrayToString = function(data){
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
};

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const scriptExecution = spawn(pythonExecutable, [myPythonScript]);

scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    var dbvalues = uint8arrayToString(data);

    console.log(dbvalues);

    mongo.connect(url ,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},function(err,db){
    var db = db.db('Dradus');
    var collection = db.collection('example');
    var query = {"name" :dbvalues};
    collection.insertOne(query, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
  });
});

});

scriptExecution.stderr.on('data', (data) => {

});

scriptExecution.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log("Process quit with code : " + code);
});
```

This code provides me an output like this but in string format
[[1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1]]. I would like it to remain in 2D array form and insert it in MongoDB like this

{number : 1,2,3,4} //first row
{number : 4,3,2,1} //second row

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse(dbvalues)`.

Comment: You receive data from python child process as String, then it is better to use JSON.parse, it will convert string to valid array format.

Comment: Thank you so much @CuongLeNgoc you literally saved my day. After parsing I was able to convert it in array of objects and insert it in my Database. Again Thank you